# SQLite: Фильтрация и диапазон элементов (запрос в проекте android)

Tags: android, sqlite

В БД SQLite есть 23 элемента.
Необходимо производить запрос по 10 элементов,

например от 1 до 10, от 11 до 20 и от 20 до 23 ( 10, 10, 3).

Делаю так:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE parent_id=7 ORDER BY name LIMIT position, 10"
```

А сам метод такой:

```
Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + MyDataBase.TABLE_DRUGS
            + " WHERE " + MyDataBase.PARENT_ID + "=" + id
            + " ORDER BY " + MyDataBase.NAME   // NAME!!!!!!!!! NO _id!!
            + " LIMIT "+ page + ", " + CommonUtilities.MAX_SIZE_MAS_FOR_DOWNLOADING);
```

**Проблема в том, что запрос на последние 3 записи (21,22,23) возвращает 10 записей (14,15,..,22,23).**

**Как изменить запрос, чтобы записи не дублировались? точнее чтоб брались только от заданной позиции и до конца, но не больше установленного в "LIMIT"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как прошёл уже почти месяц, а здесь конь не валялся, а я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, напишу ка я его здесь.

```
// на вход принимается айди=8, номер страницы=1, значения "от"=5 и "до"=9
//id,price_from,price_to - фильтры для ограничения записей, page - постраничная загрузка (1,2,3,4..)
public ArrayList<ItemDrugs> getGoods (long id, int page, double price_from, double price_to){

    String where = MyDataBase.PARENT_ID + "=" + id; // "parent_id=8 (например 8)
    where += (price_from != 0 ? " AND "+MyDataBase.PRICE + ">"+price_from : ""); // parent_id=8 AND price>5
    where += (price_to != 0 ? " AND "+MyDataBase.PRICE + "<"+price_to : ""); // parent_id=8 AND price>5 AND price<9

    int count = getCountInTable(MyDataBase.TABLE_DRUGS, where); // вызываем метод(на количество строк) и передаём условие, описанное выше. может быть 84
    int needCount = page * CommonUtilities.MAX_SIZE_MAS_FOR_DOWNLOADING; //тут номер загружаемой страницы * на 20. (20,40,60...)
    int startCount = page == 1 ? 0 : needCount - CommonUtilities.MAX_SIZE_MAS_FOR_DOWNLOADING; // если страница 1я, то берём записи с 0 позиции или
    //если page=2, startCount = (needCount)40 - 20 = 20 (startCount - стартовая позиция)

    // здесь наш любимый LIMIT. при page = 2, count = 84, needCount = 40, startCount = 20, limit будет " LIMIT 20, 20"
    // а как закачать последние 4 записи? проверим:
    // ------------------------ при page = 5, count = 84, needCount = 100, startCount = 80, limit будет " LIMIT 80, 4"
    String limit = " LIMIT " + (count < needCount ? startCount + ", " + (count-startCount) : startCount + ", " + CommonUtilities.MAX_SIZE_MAS_FOR_DOWNLOADING);

    Cursor cursor_result = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+MyDataBase.TABLE_DRUGS + " WHERE "+ where + " "+limit);
    Log.e(TAG, "SELECT * FROM "+MyDataBase.TABLE_DRUGS + " WHERE "+ where + " "+limit);

    ArrayList<ItemDrugs> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor_result.moveToNext()) {
        ItemDrugs item = new ItemDrugs();
        item.setId(cursor_result.getInt(cursor_result.getColumnIndex(MyDataBase.ID)));
        item.setName(cursor_result.getString(cursor_result.getColumnIndex(MyDataBase.NAME)));
        item.setDescription(cursor_result.getString(cursor_result.getColumnIndex(MyDataBase.DESCR)));

        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Метод, который возвращает количество записей по условию или без него:

```
public int getCountInTable(String table, String where){
    Cursor cursor;
    if (where != null){
        cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT("+ MyDataBase.ID+") FROM " + table + " WHERE " + where);
    } else {
        cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT("+ MyDataBase.ID+") FROM " + table);
    }
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Хоть это, можно сказать "костыль", но код рабочий, другого способа работы с LIMIT не нашёл. Либо **"LIMIT 20"** - выборка от 0 до 20(не включительно до 20), либо **"LIMIT 20, 29"** - выборка от 20 позиции с ограничением в 29 элементов. **Но!** если у вас 25 записей, а вы пишите "LIMIT 20, 29", то он не вернёт вам 5 записей(они же как бы последние), а вернёт все 29, но они ещё и повторяющиеся!

Так вот - рабочий "Костыль". Будут вопросы по коду - обращайтесь ;)